# VBA: Value change on a dropdown in IE doesn't update report

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I'm automating the download of a report. There is a dropdown for status that needs changing to the value "Started". I've managed to change the value in my code but when you manually make the change the report screen for the site updates automatically. My code doesn't manage to do this.

I'm wondering if there's an extra element that might need changing. Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

element on the site:

```
<select data-bind="value: leads.overall_status, options: [null, 'not_started', 'quoted_with_quotes', 'quoted_without_quotes', 'started', 'open_accounts'], optionsText: BrokerLeadsGridModel.overall_status_renderer" style="width: 160px;vertical-align: baseline;display: inline;" class="form-control">
<option value="">Any</option>
<option value="not_started">Not Started</option>
<option value="quoted_with_quotes">Quoted</option>
<option value="quoted_without_quotes">No Quotes</option>
<option value="started">Started</option>
<option value="open_accounts">Open</option>
</select>
```

My Code:

```
Doc.getElementsByClassName("form-control")(0).Value = "started"
```

Comment: Have you tried `.fireevent ("onclick")`?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I've not no. How would I use this in my code?

Comment: After your code or selecting the value add `Doc.getElementsByClassName("form-control")(0).fireevent ("onclick")` - you can try "onchange" instead of "onclick" as well, I'm just blind guessing

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I gave it a try, but both suggestions haven't updated. I'm sure this will prove helpful in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try attribute = value css selector?

```
doc.querySelector("[value=started]").selected = True
```

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I've just tried this out, it's not making the change unfortunately. I'm going to read more into this querySelector method though, there must be something I can trigger